# Blogger: How to center align header image?

Tags: blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

[image: mobile view of the blog] https://rummyraani.blogspot.com
This is my blog's mobile view. How do I get the header image to the center aligned position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **theme** > **Customize** > **Advanced** > **Add CSS**

```
.header-widget {
    text-align: center;
}
```